# X Windows-esque JS UI Client

Tags: javascript, web-applications, graphics, raphael, x11

All,

I've had an idea kicking around for a while now: Is there a standard graphics library/protocol like X Windows for HTML+JS? I'm primarily a desktop developer with experience in technologies like C#/WPF, but I'd like my piece of the web revolution. :)

To me most web technologies for displaying interactive apps seem to be too proprietary, slow, or graphically poor compared to what I expect from a desktop app on even a slow computer. It seems like if there were a way to use an abstracted graphical and user input layer and solid quasi-two-way communication, it wouldn't be terribly difficult to make true desktop apps displayed in nearly all browsers.

Now what I'm saying isn't just idle chat: I've gotten a little something cooked up with WPF to start extracting graphics primitives at the milcore layer and am pushing those out across the web using simulated sockets via orbited and Raphael for front-side rendering primarily as a fun hack. So far it wasn't that hard, so I figure somebody else must have done it. WPF isn't everybody's cup of tea, but on the flip side many folks would probably love to have a solid OOP language to code most of the backend stuff with a standardized graphics protocol to the front end that's not just HTML/CSS.

Now to me this seems like a very basic thing - a truly graphical client in the browser, on almost all browsers, sans plugins. We have browsers that can do all these high-level things and play audio and videos. I just want to draw triangles that can change. I assume I've just missed the boat and am reinventing the wheel. Can somebody please point me to a project that does this already so I can make some awesome web apps?

Comment: +1 for asking a question that shook up my mental model of the web a little (though I'm not full sure I understand it).  Are you thinking of the web browser as a _thin_ client of sorts?  Or kind of like a web-based remote access tool (ala LogMeIn, GoToMyPC, etc) that accesses a _back-end_ model of the UI?  I have similar reservations as @jordancpaul about performance - you'd need constant chatter with the server if the client has to wait for the backend to tell it what to render.

Comment: Back-end model of the UI is probably the closest. The beauty is that the backend doesn't necessarily have to be "back-end" either. With an appropriate protocol in place, the back-end could be in JS on the same box, just appropriately abstracted away. In this way, the code and the presentation become a bit more standardized and separated. As for performance, yes that's going to be a problem. Using an appropriate transport though, I bet it could get down to about 100ms lag or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're interested in **low level** control from **the backend** at **run time** is probably a show-stopper, unless you can accept lots of lag.

It takes a lot longer to communicate between the server and client in the web world.  In a desktop, the lags are not worthy of measurement, but on the web, with HTTP requests, the delays are real, highly variable and potentially UX-destroying.

1. Client notices a user click and calls out to let the server know (+50-500ms to transfer)
2. Server finds out, issues an instruction to animate a triangle (+100ms to process)
   (+50ms-500ms to transfer)
3. Client gets instruction, animates triangle (**user perceived lag: 200ms to 1100ms**)

So... I'm not sure the *exact* architecture you're thinking of is feasible on the web.

If you revisit your assumptions a little, your options grow quite a bit.  Removing the requirement to make roundtrips all the way to the backend for the application logic, for instance, would be very liberating.  Try this interpretation of the desktop paradigm on for size:

- X-Windows → *The browser rendering engine (lowest level API, equivalent to hardware)*
- WPF → *SVG, Raphael, jQueryUI etc. (higher level drawing APIs)*
- C# application logic → *Client-side JS logic ([OOP style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript))*
- File system → *Web Server with DB*

Interesting question!

Comment: Well, you've got some solid points there. I really want the ability to avoid needing to code JS to make it all go (other than a base client that does some connections) because I've tried OOP style JS at least somewhat and I miss my C#. :D Also, it's much nicer from a security side to have a true thin client. However, if nobody else can come up with something better in a couple days, I think the points should go to you. By the way, have you seen this? It came up since I posted: http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2011/03/15/gtk-html-backend-update/

Comment: Interesting link.  Like VNC except rather than spitting raster images out to the client, it spits out HTML...  I hope I *don't* get any points - I'd rather see an ingenius solution than somebody whining about how it shouldn't work!

Comment: Also, if you ignore the whole "UI model on the backend" issue, and were just concerned with abstracting the HTML/CSS/JS layers, you might take a look at http://www.openlaszlo.org/ - which uses a Flex-like markup language above it all.

Comment: Well, the points are yours. I'm going to leave it unanswered, in case we can get some more comments on this whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a library that makes the process of putting together a UI less of an HTML piecemeal effort. Well, it's worth stating the obvious; unless something drastic happens in the near future all plugin-free web apps will, ultimately, be based on HTML+JS. 
Raphael is a great tool for generalizing graphics calls on all browsers providing a consistent drawing API, however it is not meant to be a UI solution by itself.

You might want to take a look at extJs, now a part of [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com). I have used it myself for a fairly elaborate internal BOM management tool. It provides a massive collection of ready-to-use UI components, much like WPF. It also provides an integrated RPC mechanism for integration with server-side logic.

Comment: I guess I'm not necessarily looking for just a library that makes making UIs on the web easier. Many of those exist, and many of them make some sort of JS/HTML widget - that's what Sencha does too? (HTML+remoting) If you look at what X Windows does, it defines a low-level drawing spec where a dumb terminal draws things received from the server and communicates user input, etc. back to the server. I think a similar model could work here: the HTML/JS engine would only be in charge of rendering drawing instructions from the server and routing user input back to the server. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see what you mean, however I wonder what sort of performance you would get out of that. This would mean throwing away all the core HTML elements and drawing your UI with very low-level calls. I assume, also, that this would mean UI event handling would have to be done on the server as well. I am not too familiar with the inner workings of x windows, other than that whenever the server is off the local network, applications tend to be sluggish. However, a server-side way to define the client would certainly be nice.

Answer (score 0):

There are
Several companies, don't have the names on hand, that have pure javascript RDP clients that work well. There is also an open source project called Guacamole which can talk RDP and VNC.

You run their server on a machine that has Remote Desktop Services and it acts as a websockets gateway to the "client". Works beautifully. We're going to use it for an application where there are huge amounts of data feeding the UI.

Imagine having to write a complicated application that took 10 million data points and allowed you to zoom in to any zoom level. Creating a web app to do that would be a waste of resources.

With websockets available now in most browsers, I'm frankly surprised that I don't see this more often. I'm sure

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look at products like RemoteSpark or have you found an alternative solution? We're still working with RemoteSpark, but are open to see what other people are doing.